# alignat adds extra spacing

Tags: spacing, alignat

I want to achieve the following, except without the weird extra indentation before `c`.

[image]

Also, what's with the lack of spacing between `=` and `b`, as well as between `+` and `d`? Is there a better way to fix it than just adding `\:`?

Here's my code:

```
\begin{alignat*} {2}
a = & b + (&& c \\
&& + d) \\
& + g
\end{alignat*}
```

EDIT: To clarify, here's what I was looking for. I got it with daleif's solution.

[image]

EDIT 2: Turns out daleif's solution doesn't work with a long third line:

[image]

Comment: Try `ggggggggggg\hidewidth`.

Comment: It works! Though, it feels like a pretty ad-hoc solution, and there's probably some example where it doesn't work. Isn't there a way to do something like `123\addNewIndentation{1}456 \addNewIndentation{2}789` and then the new line `\indent{1} blabla` aligns with the `4` and `\indent{2} blabla` aligns with the `7`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use

```
\begin{alignat*} {2}
a = {}& b + (&& c \\ % <- added {}
&&& + d) \\ % <- added extra &
& + g
\end{alignat*}
```

---

Update: (please always make relevant MWEs instead of wasting peoples time). In this case (especially because it is not numbered) I'd use

```
\begin{align*} 
a = {}& b +
\!
\begin{aligned}[t]
  (& c \\
  & + d)
\end{aligned}
\\
& + ggggggggggggggggggggggggg
\end{align*}
```

Comment: I thought this'd work at first, but see edited OP.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you require?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a =  b &+ (c \\
& \phantom{+(c}+ d) \\
& + g
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

or use this for the same output:

```
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 a =  b& + ( c& \\
 && + d) \\
 & + g&
\end{alignat*}
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer daleif's solution, but your first solution with `\phantom` could be modified to give the desired output (see edited OP).

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps this?  It's not completely clear, actually.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    a &= b&{}+ (c \\
        &&{}+ d) \\
    & + g
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Note that `&` should precede `=`, not follow it.

**Post edited** because of forgotten `{}`.

**Addition:**

Please don't think I'm to fussy if I insist that `&` shuld be placed *before* `=`: this makes the extra `{}` unnecessary.  Input:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    a &= b + (&&c \\
         &&&+ d) \\
    & {}+ g
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Placing `&` before `=` makes the third line appear too far to the left.

Comment: @Blrp: …So, you are saying that what is wanted here is to align the + sign on the last line with the b on the first: OK, now I understand your code, I misunderstood the goal you want to achieve.